# Find the value of $\sin25^° \sin35^° \sin85^°$

Tags: trigonometry

Trigo problem :

Find the value of $\sin25^° \sin35^° \sin85^°$.

My approach :

Using $2\sin A\sin B = \cos(A-B) -\cos(A+B)$

$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}}[\cos10^{°} -\cos60^°] \sin85^° \\
& = \frac{1}{2}[2\cos10^°\sin85^° -2\cos60^° \sin85^°] \\
& = \frac{1}{2}[2\cos10^°\sin85^° -2 \frac{1}{2} \sin85^°] \\
& = \frac{1}{2}[2\cos10^°\sin85^° -\sin85^°] \\
& = \frac{1}{2} [\sin 95^° + \sin 75^° -\sin85^°]
\end{align}
$$

After this I am unable to solve further.... please guide... thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\sin(95^\circ)=\sin(85^\circ)$.

We can get an explicit formula for $\sin(75^\circ)$ in various ways, probably most simply by writing it as $\sin(30^\circ+45^\circ)$ and using the Addition Law.

Comment: oh! got it thanks.. I skipped that cancellation of sin $95^{\circ} $ and $sin85^{\circ}$ .. thanks once againthanks..

Comment: You are welcome. A surprising result!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} \sin25^{°}\sin35^{°}\sin85^{°} \\
& =\sin85^{°}\sin35^{°}\sin25^{°} \\
& =\frac{1}{2}(2\sin85^{°}\sin35^{°})\sin25^{°} \\
& =\frac{1}{2}[ \cos50^{°} -\cos120^{°}] \sin25^{°}  \\
& = \frac{1}{4}[ 2\cos50^{°}\sin25^{°} +2\cos60^{°} \sin25^{°}] \\
& = \frac{1}{4}[ 2\cos50^{°}\sin25^{°} +2 \frac{1}{2} \sin25^{°}] \\
& = \frac{1}{4}[ 2\cos50^{°}\sin25^{°} +\sin25^{°}] \\
& = \frac{1}{4} [ \sin75^{°} -\sin 25^{°} +\sin25^{°}] \\
& =\frac{1}{4}  \sin75^{°}
\end{align}

Comment: Awesome work- am amazed

Answer (score 0):

on can use the identity

$\sin3x=4\sin x\sin\left(60^{\circ}-x\right)\sin\left(60^{\circ}+x\right)$
, $x=25^{\circ}$
, $\sin75^{\circ}=4\sin25^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}\sin85^{\circ}$
, $\sin25^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}\sin85^{\circ}=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin75^{\circ}=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{16}$